# cannot perform this operation on a closed dataset and incorrect data entered into table

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-2010

I have been getting this error and I am struggling to find what I have done wrong. What doesn't make sense is that the result is still posted to the database with all fields being correct except the name field. In the name field it enters 'dmInfo' for some reason.

```
with dmQuery_u.dmInfo do
      begin
        dsInfo.Edit;
        qryData.SQL.Clear;
        qryData.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM eventinfo ORDER BY eventnumber');
        qryData.Open;
        qryData.Last;
        autonum := qryData['eventnumber'] + 1;
        qryData.SQL.Clear;
        qryData.SQL.Add(
          'INSERT INTO eventinfo (eventnumber, bandname, venue, dateofevent, ticketcost, openingact, amountbooked)');
        qryData.SQL.Add(
          'VALUES (:eventnumber, :bandname, :venue, :dateofevent, :ticketcost, :openingact, :amountbooked)');
        qryData.Parameters.ParamByName('eventnumber').Value := autonum;
        qryData.Parameters.ParamByName('bandname').Value := name;
        qryData.Parameters.ParamByName('venue').Value := venue;
        qryData.Parameters.ParamByName('dateofevent').Value := date;
        qryData.Parameters.ParamByName('ticketcost').Value := ticketcost;
        qryData.Parameters.ParamByName('openingact').Value := openingact;
        qryData.Parameters.ParamByName('amountbooked').Value := amountbooked;
        qryData.ExecSQL;
        qryData.SQL.Clear;
        qryData.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM eventinfo');
        qryData.Last;
        qryData.Open;
```

Comment: cannot perform this operation on a closed dataset will usually point you to the operation you are trying to do on a closed dataset. `qryData.Last;
        qryData.Open;` looks suspicious.

Comment: If what you are trying to do is to pick up the highest existing value of EventNum and add 1 to it for a new row, this is a horribly inefficient and error-prone way of doing it.  Which back-end server are you using?

Comment: Yes, the typical way to do this is to use an autoincrementing index field.

Comment: The with clause is useless! Remove it at once

Answer (score 2):

Your error is being caused here :

```pascal
 qryData.ExecSQL;
 qryData.SQL.Clear;
 qryData.SQL.Add('SELECT * FROM eventinfo');
 qryData.Last;  { !! should be after ---v }
 qryData.Open;  { should be first ---^ }
```

Calling `.ExecSQL` executes a non-query (ie : returns no recordset) command.  Since there is no valid dataset here, calling `.Last` will throw an error.  You have to call `.Open` first.

For the second issue of your `name` field populating with `dmInfo`, you're being caught out by use of the dangerous `with` statement here:

```pascal
 with dmQuery_u.dmInfo do
   {...}
    qryData.Parameters.ParamByName('bandname').Value := name;
```

Here the `with` statement is hiding the `name` variable you want to use and is instead interpreting it as `dmQuery_u.dmInfo.Name`.  Either get rid of the `with` statement and use explicit qualifiers for everything or change the name of your `name` variable.

Comment: So, is it recommended that I should change my code so it does not use the 'with' statement?

Comment: @PhilipEllis Either that or change the name of the `name` variable.  The subject of the `with` statement is a matter of some strong opinion.  There are valid use cases for it, but generally when the `with` block starts to become large the probability of scoping errors such as this tends to increase.